# How to convert time to string and leave NaT as-is in Python df?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a df in Python I'm trying to load to Snowflake. Its contents are currently either a Timestamp() datatype or literal NaT. The problematic column, when loaded currently, looks like:

[image]

And the source of those two rows looks like:

```
DEACTIVATED_AT
NaT
Timestamp('2020-06-20 01:47:15')
```

I need to convert the Timestamp to a literal string but df['DEACTIVATED_AT'].astype(str) will error with the NaT in Snowflake, because it is trying to insert the literal 'NaT' string to the DB.

```
ProgrammingError: 100071 (22000): Failed to cast variant value "NaT" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ
```

How can I leave the NaT's as they were and only convert the Timestamp's to strings?

I've tried:

```
df['DEACTIVATED_AT'] = df['DEACTIVATED_AT'].fillna(np.datetime64('NaT')).astype(str)
#converts NaT to string still
```

```
df['DEACTIVATED_AT'] = df['DEACTIVATED_AT'].apply(lambda v: str(v) if not pd.isnull(v) else v).tolist()
#Leaves NaT correct but doesn't convert the Timestamps for some reason
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try this, not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
df['DEACTIVATED_AT'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').fillna(pd.NaT)
```

- convert `DEACTIVATED_AT` from datetime to str.
- because NaT would convert into NaN during the conversion, you can do `fillna()` to replace NaN with NaT.
- however, the column dtype would be as `object` instead of `datetime64[ns]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'DEACTIVATED_AT' : [pd.NaT, pd.Timestamp('2020-06-20 01:47:15')]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# now do the work
df['test'] = df['DEACTIVATED_AT'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not pd.isnull(x) else pd.NaT)
```

will give

```
    DEACTIVATED_AT      test
0   NaT                 NaT
1   2020-06-20 01:47:15 2020-06-20
```

and

```
df['test'] = df['DEACTIVATED_AT'].apply(lambda x: str(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) if not pd.isnull(x) else str(pd.NaT))
```

gives

```
    DEACTIVATED_AT      test
0   NaT                 NaT
1   2020-06-20 01:47:15 2020-06-20 01:47:15
```

with

```
df.dtypes
```

as

```
DEACTIVATED_AT    datetime64[ns]
test                      object
dtype: object
```

and

```
print(type(df['test'][1]))
```

giving

```
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, the issue is still that df.iloc[1]['test'] returns a Timestamp datatype, even though it looks like a string at first glance. Do you have a solution that converts the cell value to string, including the hour, min, seconds?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, making everything strings with a unique string in place of the NaT's to later substitute back:

```
df['DEACTIVATED_AT'] = df['DEACTIVATED_AT'].fillna('sub').astype(str).replace('sub',np.nan)
```

I had to use np.nan rather than pd.NaT to avoid this pyarrow error:

```
ArrowTypeError: ('an integer is required (got type str)', 'Conversion failed for column DEACTIVATED_AT with type object')
```

Open to more elegant solutions though!